# Transition from LSA to non LSA

Tags: ppl

If you obtain your PPL (Private Pilot License) in an LSA (Light Sport Aircraft), do you have to go for additional training or certification for other SEL (Single Engine Land) aircraft (ie. Cessnas), or how would that work?

Comment: Can you please write out what LSA and SEL mean in full? Also what country are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I’ll assume from the terminology that you’re asking about FAA rules.

If you have a PPL ASEL, then as far as the FAA is concerned, you are legal to operate any ASEL that does not require any additional endorsement (complex, high performance or tail wheel) or a type rating.

However, in practice, it is highly unlikely you will be able to do so without additional training.  No insurer will cover you without a minimum amount of time in type, and nobody will rent a plane to you either because *their* insurer will require similar time in type. But how do you *get* time in type without already having that time in type?

This is solved by getting “transition” training. By the time that is complete and the CFI is satisfied you can safely operate the new type solo (which typically amounts to being able to pass a BFR/IPC, whether or not they do the paperwork making that official), you will probably have the minimum required hours.